# Occurencia de valores en una lista doble enlazada en Java

Tags: java, lista

Estoy aprendiendo java y estoy trabajando con nodos, deseo crear un método que me devuelva los valores mas usados en la lista y cuantas veces se usa cada uno, sin embargo, a la hora de imprimir los valores, el método no me devuelve exactamente lo que deseo

El código de los nodos

```
public class Nodo {
    int x;
    boolean empty;
    Nodo next;
    Nodo before;

    public Nodo(int v)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        x = v;
        next=null;
        before = null;
    }

    public Nodo()
    {
        x = 0;
        next=null;
        before = null;
    }

    public int getVal(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setNext(Nodo next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setBefore(Nodo before)
    {
        this.before = before;
    }
}
```

Uno de los métodos que insertan un nodo y el método que debe regresar la ocurrencia deseada.

```
public class Lista {
    Nodo cabeza;
    Nodo cola;
    Nodo siguiente;
    Nodo anterior;
    int dimension = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Lista() {
        cabeza=null;
        cola=null;
    }
    public void addStart(int v) {
        Nodo g = new Nodo(v);
        if(cabeza == null) {
            cabeza = g;
        } else {
            g.setNext(cabeza);
            cabeza.setBefore(g);
            cabeza = g;           
        }
        dimension++;
        list.add(0, v);
    }
public void ocurrence() {

    Nodo recorre = cabeza;
    int array[] = new int [size()];
    int contador = 0;
    int frec = 1;
    int valor = -1;
    int frecuencia;
    int modal = 0;       
    for(int i = 0 ;i < size(); i++) {
        array[i] = recorre.getVal();
        recorre = recorre.next;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        frecuencia = 1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++ ) {
            if(array[i] == array[j])
                frecuencia++;
        }
        for(int z = 0; z < array.length; z++) {
            modal = frecuencia;
            valor = array[i];
            System.out.println("El elemento " + valor +
                    " se repite " + modal + " veces.");
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que veo los nodos se insertan bien y parecen estar enlazados, sin embargo, el problema es la impresión en si, supongo que este último

```
   for(int z = 0; z < array.length; z++) {
       modal = frecuencia;
       valor = array[i];
       System.out.println("El elemento " + valor + " se repite " + modal + " veces.");
   }
```

El método imprime los valores pero imprime una linea del resultado por cada nodo o valor en la lista, para cada valor, en vez de hacerlo una vez por valor.

He intentado varias cosas pero no me han funcionado, no se si sera un error muy obvio de lógica o estoy completamente perdido.

Comment: ??? Lo primero que haces es crear un array con la misma longitud de la lista y copiar los valores de cada nodo de la lista (repetido o no) allí. Y luego trabajas con ese array ignorando la posibilidad de valores repetidos.